# Populating an array of arrays in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongoose

I am trying to populate in an array of arrays. The schema looks like this:

```
const IngredientAttachment = {
    ingredient: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Ingredient.modelName, required: true },
    // there's more fields here
};


const mealSchema = new Schema({
    ingredients: [[ IngredientAttachment ]] // array of array of attachments
    // there's more fields here
});
```

An example unpopulated `Meal` document looks like this:

```
{
  "ingredients": [
    [{
        "_id": "5bcf9b3f2e33ad15f52bd831",
        "ingredient": "5bce60f074c12923c589db90"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5bcf9c94652b8f164f6a2566",
        "ingredient": "5bce85b76bb8812b2eb5322c"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I tried to use this:

```
meal = await meal
    .populate({
        path: 'ingredients',
        populate: {
            path: 'ingredient',
        }
    })
```

but that doesn't do anything :)

Thanks!

EDIT: For now I "solved" it by introducing a field `options`:

```
ingredients: [{
    options: [ IngredientAttachment ]
}]
```

Where I need the meal as an array of arrays of ingredients I just transform it like this:

```
meal.ingredients = meal.ingredients.map(m => m.options);
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No, it just doesn't populate it. It keeps it as an ID

Comment: Is `meal` a Query, a Model or a Document? (Asking in context of `meal.populate(...)`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
meal.find({}).populate('ingredients.ingredient').exec(...)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but it doesn't work. I think it's the same actually as the example I showed.

Answer (score 0):

Below the solution to your problem.

Ingredient Schema File:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ingredient = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Ingredient', ingredient);
```

Ingredient Attachment Schema File:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ingredientAttachment = new mongoose.Schema({
    ingredient: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Ingredient',
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('IngredientAttachment', ingredientAttachment);
```

Meal Schema File:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mealSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ingredients: {
        type: [[
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'IngredientAttachment',
                required: true
            }
        ]]
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Meal', mealSchema);
```

This is the code that I used for tests:

```
    const ingredientA = new ingredientSchema({name: 'ingredientA'});
    await ingredientA.save();
    console.log(`ingredientA=${ingredientA}`);

    const ingredientB = new ingredientSchema({name: 'ingredientB'});
    await ingredientB.save();
    console.log(`ingredientB=${ingredientB}`);

    const ingredientC = new ingredientSchema({name: 'ingredientC'});
    await ingredientC.save();
    console.log(`ingredientC=${ingredientC}`);

    const ingredientD = new ingredientSchema({name: 'ingredientD'});
    await ingredientD.save();
    console.log(`ingredientD=${ingredientD}`);

    const ingredientAttachmentA = new ingredientAttachmentSchema({ingredient: ingredientA, description: 'descriptionA'});
    await ingredientAttachmentA.save();
    console.log(`ingredientAttachmentA=${ingredientAttachmentA}`);

    const ingredientAttachmentB = new ingredientAttachmentSchema({ingredient: ingredientB, description: 'descriptionB'});
    await ingredientAttachmentB.save();
    console.log(`ingredientAttachmentB=${ingredientAttachmentB}`);

    const ingredientAttachmentC = new ingredientAttachmentSchema({ingredient: ingredientC, description: 'descriptionC'});
    await ingredientAttachmentC.save();
    console.log(`ingredientAttachmentC=${ingredientAttachmentC}`);

    const ingredientAttachmentD = new ingredientAttachmentSchema({ingredient: ingredientD, description: 'descriptionD'});
    await ingredientAttachmentD.save();
    console.log(`ingredientAttachmentD=${ingredientAttachmentD}`);

    const meal = new mealSchema({
        ingredients: [[ingredientAttachmentA, ingredientAttachmentB], [ingredientAttachmentC, ingredientAttachmentD]],
        type: 'spicy'
    });
    await meal.save();
    console.log(`meal=${meal}`);

    const mealPopulated = await mealSchema.find({_id:meal._id}).populate({
        path: 'ingredients',
        model: 'IngredientAttachment',
        populate: { path:  'ingredient',
                    model: 'Ingredient' }
    }).exec();
    console.log('------ mealPopulated ------');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(mealPopulated, null, 0));
```

This is the output after execution:

[image: mongoose meal populated]

Populate json formatted:

[image: json formatted]

Comment: Thank you for putting in so much time, I appreciate it! I think what you did is different from what I need though. My Meal schema is not an array of arrays of ingredient references but an array of arrays of objects where each object contains several fields, including an ingredient reference. I added some comments to make this clearer. Again, thanks!

Comment: In this case, you have 3 schemas(Meal, IngredientAttachment, and Ingredient), right?

Comment: @Yaeger I updated my answer with the 3 schemas, now I believe that will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, but still this is not really what I was looking for. As you can see in my example, IngredientAttachment is not a separate schema. I just extracted this object, so my `Meal` schema would be a bit more clear. Look at my edit, I wrote down how I "solved" it.